# Creating a Discord bot with javascript and something is wrong

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating my first discord bot in JavaScript and since most of the code is a big if statement I am working on the else part. I can't identify the problem with it as with the text editor I am using(Sublime) with the javascript syntax it displays if, else if, and else as red and the last else statement is white how do I fix this to make sure my code is proper

```
...
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if(message.substring(0) == '!generate stats') {
        ...

    }else {

    }
```

The main problem I have been experiencing is with the text editor I am using(Sublime 3). Where the else statement at the end isn't being registered as one and it has concerned if my code is correct. It might just be the text editor but better safe than sorry.

Bottom else is the Problem

[image]

Comment: Sublime is a pretty mature editor. It's likely that if it's flagging something then there is an issue with your code. Why do you have () after your final else statement?

Comment: sort of a place holder but I guess other than that no real reason

Comment: Please [edit] your question and trim it down to a [mcve]. By doing so you may even find the problem yourself. What errors do you get when you run the code? That may give you more information about the problem than what syntax highlighting gives. Quick guess: `else` probably does not take a condition (as in e.g., your `else (biomeGen2 == 7)`); that's where you need `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

else statement does not need `()` for it.

You can just use

```
if (something){
 . . .
}
else {
 . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks I applied said advice but still hasn't fixed the problem thanks anyways though

Comment: Are you sure you fixed it all? There are many else statements of yours that have conditions in it.

Comment: Your biggest `if` does have `;` at the end of it while it shouldn't.

Comment: which if are you talking about biggest is a bit vague in my current predicament

Comment: Check your every `if` statement. None of them should have `;` at the end of it.

Comment: ok I deleted all ; after if statements sublime still hasn't fixed it though

Comment: Actually, if you follow Sublime and resolve all of the issues it throws then it would be fine.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "follow Sublime"?

Comment: Sublime will display what error it is currently having. You can just follow it and fix it accordingly.

Comment: Thing is sublime isn't saying there is an error but the syntax is being weird with the last else statement even though it should be red for logic it is white if that makes sense

Comment: Please update your question what it is now. Providing images of it will help too.